# How to set up VueJS second level data property to an input value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this html code:

```
<div id="app">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="user.name">
</div>
```

With this Vue.js code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
           user: {
                   name: 'John Doe',
                   age: 20
           },
           // etc...
    }
});
```

How can I show the Vue's data.user.name propertie's value in input filed?

If I try this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" v-model="user.name" value="user.name">
```

Then it says `user is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `value` attribute using `v-bind`

```
<input type="text" name="username" v-bind:value="user.name">
```

Or using the shorthand of `v-bind`

```
    <input type="text" name="username" :value="user.name">
```

Or use a `v-model`

```
       <input type="text" name="username" v-model="user.name">
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/36phod86/2/)